# Unable to access wso2 apim 4.0.0.0 publisher console in Openshift

Tags: wso2, openshift, wso2-api-manager

We are trying to do a container based setup of WSO2 APIM 4.0.0.0 on Openshift and we have installed the apim on it and all the applications are Running and even URL is being connected to Host tried to do curl in terminal of apim-publisher, but unable to access url https://wso2apim-publisher-route-wso2-deploy.apps.cloud.admcoecloud.local/publisher, page is not opening it is being redirected to localhost. All routes are installed as well:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rujCW.jpg)

Need suggestion on how to access publishers, carbon and store in this scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the hostname as in [1]

```
[server]
hostname = "am.dev.wso2.com"
```

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/install-and-setup/setup/deployment-best-practices/changing-the-hostname/#changing-the-hostname

Comment: Not able to find this deployment.toml file in Openshift Console

Comment: You need to change the deployment.toml file of wso2 api manager. If you don't have a configmap, then you will have to create a one

Comment: Ok I will try to do this. Thank you!

Comment: I did edit hostname in deployment.toml file and added it to ConfigMaps but still it is being redirected to https://localhost:9443

Comment: Did you mount the configmap in the deployment as in https://github.com/wso2/kubernetes-apim/blob/master/advanced/am-pattern-1/templates/am/instance-1/wso2am-pattern-1-am-deployment.yaml#L110?